# Доступ к файлу Java

Tags: java, android, файлы

в assets создан файл text.txt .
Я проверяю его существование, и мне пишет что его нет, хотя он есть
Что не так?

```
File file = new File("text.txt");
    boolean res = file.exists();
    String s1 = (res == true) ? ("Да файла") : ("Нет файла");
    System.out.println(s1);
```

Выводит Нет

Comment: Оформите код в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Answer (score 2):

Файлы, находящиеся в директории assets при компиляции попадают в итоговый apk файл, поэтому обратиться к ним способом, который Вы используете, невозможно.
Для того, чтобы получить доступ к файлу используйте класс AssetManager:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open("text.txt");
```

Далее делаете с файлом то, что Вам нужно. Например, можете построчно вывести файл в стандартный вывод (взято [отсюда](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/how-to-read-data-from-inputstream-into-string-in-java/))

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: А если я хочу знать путь до файла из Assets?

Comment: @V.Ivanova Вы можете воспользоваться методом list объекта am и получить массив всех файлов находящихся на указанном пути. В массиве проверяйте искомый файл на присутствие.

Comment: но это же выводит лишь имена файлов

Comment: @V.Ivanova Уточните, пожалуйста, чуть более развернуто в чем состоит трудность

Comment: @V.Ivanova до файлов в папке ```assett``` нет пути, т.к. они находится прямо в apk файле

Comment: мне нужно будет построчно прочитать данные из этого файла

Comment: @V.Ivanova Поправил ответ